# What is the reason behind disallowing to change a vote?

Tags: discussion

What is the rationale behind this?

> You last voted on this answer 8 hours ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.

I used the code 8 hours ago, it worked. I use it under different circumstances now, turns out it breaks and another answer (from another question) does work. So the answer is buggy and I want to remove my upvote and add a comment, but I am unable to change my vote. Why?

Comment: it is supposed to prevent "tactical" voting: downvote competing answers so yours rises to the top, looks better and is more likely to be accepted; then reverse the vote(s) later when one is accepted.  At least in part.

Comment: If someone is that childish, why would they remove their downvote later? To get that one reputation point back?

Comment: Yes, that's probably the reason. Right now, "tactical voting" costs rep permanently because you can't undo the votes. If you could undo the votes and get the rep back, it would be easier/more attractive to do it repeatedly.

Comment: Just leave the comment anyway or edit the answer if you can and you have a fix for the bug.

Comment: well if you need to do that, you might be answering [simple / stupid questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26443848/1070452) where there are often multiple answers and would take 3 or more DVs to float yours to the top.  Do that a lot and the tactical DVs could result in negative rep if you dont get some accepted answers.  It is also meant to cause you to stop and think before up or down voting.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Hmm actually, why is my upvote locked now? Shouldn't only downvotes be locked? And I don't even have an answer to that question, so I can't be voting tactically.

Comment: Related: ["What is the justification for locking votes?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70853/what-is-the-justification-for-locking-votes)

Answer (score -4):

Some possible reasons for this include

- ruins morale of users when they get upvoted and then a week/month later they get that reversed and even a new downvote maybe.
- teaches users to vote the right way the first time by reading and understanding the post first and then making your decision
- slows down rage-quitters who would like to go through all their upvotes they've ever done and change them downvotes instead just to wreak havoc

Comment: Quitters get their votes removed anyway except in exceptional circumstances.

Comment: @MartinSmith not everyone requests for their account to be deleted.. some of them just rage-quit and don't ever log in again. So they still have the account since they didn't go through the proper channels to have it removed!

Comment: So there's nothing stopping them just down voting 40 random posts per day anyway. Why would they specifically target posts they previously found useful?

Comment: @MartinSmith who knows. I've just noticed that previous rage quitters that were brought to meta's attention before  , would *unaccept* all their answers they accepted previously. So that is specifically targeting posts they found useful.